# Zend: Is there anyway to disable init function for ajax requests?

Tags: zend-framework

I am making an ajax call to one of my controller. But every time i make a call the init() is executed (that's how init() works). So is there any way to disable the execution of an init()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be just to check if it's an Ajax request inside the init:

```
public function init()
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // init code here
    }       
}
```